# Nested grids using ng-grid (AngularJS)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Its Recently we started using angular js in our project. its really amazing framework, ng-grid is just like "life made easy library", we have all features in ng-grid but I'm missing just one feature which is "Nested Grids" like as in image. We want to move on 'n' level e.g product categories where we add multiple child products against one parent category.

I know ng-grid has grouping which is good , but it doesn't work for complex collections. It will be even more appreciative if ng-grid team will add this feature to their list.I tried lot of examples around but it didn't work. If any one has an hack kindly reply with the solution, it will be great help and It will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance

[image]